# WPF: Content of textbox/Combobox goes beyond window screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox/combobox displaying a particular path and both the textbox and combobox are already set to change size according to their contents. If the path is very long, it goes beyond the window screen and the "browse button" I have given gets hidden.(refer image for clarity).Note:I have this problem for both text & comboboxes.

Here's the snippet of a particular case:

```
<Label Content="_Layout Report Output Path:" Grid.Row="5" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtLytRepPath}"/>
     <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox Name="CmbLytRepPath" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LayoutReportPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Button Name="BtnLytRepPath" Style="{StaticResource BrowseButton}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Label>
```

Button Style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BrowseButton">
     <Setter Property="Content" Value="..."/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
     <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
</Style>
```

[image]

I cannot use a wrap panel as its makes the UI bad.Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Your label should not be containing the stackpanel, that's just odd.  So break those out, and then show us the xaml for how the items are laid out inside the container (i.e. the container for Report Settings)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you close twice the label.

I think you will try with a dockpanel

```
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="5" Height="??? if need">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="_xxx"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style=” ”/>
        <ComboBox />
    </DockPanel>
```

Regards

Comment: It seems the parent container is a `Grid` and the last closing label is just a (wrong) artifact in the question. So your base idea of using a `DockPanel` is good (+1), but the panel should only contain button and combobox. Additionally, I suggest to include a hint to custom `TabIndex`, since `DockPanel.Dock="Right"` doesn't really play nice with the default order.